# Find all .htaccess files that contain a particular string?

Tags: find

How would I find all the .htaccess files (recursively from current folder) that contain a particular string ('common.php') in my case?

What would be the command to do so?

Answer (score 1):

If your shell is `zsh` or `bash`:

```
grep 'common\.php'  **/.htaccess
```

(`**` expands to any depth of subdirectories.)

Answer (score 1):

This command will search *all files* in the current directory for that string:

```
grep -r "common.php" .
```

This had the advantage of it gives the filename - a better thing will probably be in @Rmano 's answer.

This will search for the `.htaccess` file, then run grep on it.

```
find . -type f -iname '.htaccess' -exec grep -r "common.php" {} \;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
find . -name '.htaccess' -print | xargs grep 'common.php'
```